# MVC Url missing subdomain name

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Url Like

> www.example.com/subdomain

Url Is [Audit Trail](/Audit/Index)
Ajax call on page load

```
var url = '/Audit/GetAllActionsLog';
  AjaxPostRequestWithoutRequestPerameters(url, function (response) {

});
```

When click on url it should be url

> www.example.com/subdomain/Audit/Index

but missing subdomain name i am seeing

> www.example.com/Audit/Index

Comment: remove leading `/` and try, it points to domain

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're using `a href="/Audit/Index"` instead use `a href="Audit/Index"`

The backslash at the front denotes you're going back in a directory.
Hope it helps.